# How to shrink container in flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I want my container to shrink when page is smaller. How can i do that?

```
.home-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ffefd0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 1px grey;
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
}
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider adding a reproducible example in the future. As far as what you have, you will likely need to look into `@media` queries which will allow you to control element sizing based on screen size. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media There are examples on SO and in that article that you can use to aid you. :)

Comment: your question lacks more details about the situation, the only solution that i can come up with is using `max-width: 800px` instead of `width: 800px`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a set width. It's best to avoid setting height and width (when possible) to avoid problems with responsiveness. Instead of width, use max-width: 800px.

Answer (score 0):

Do not provide width property as you have passed it ... instead add padding to that container accordingly and set width property to max-width like this

```
.home-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ffefd0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 1px grey;
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
  padding:20px;
  width: max-width;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this ??

```css
.home-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ffefd0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 1px grey;
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  grid-gap:10px;
  height:auto;
 }
 
.box {
  height:80px;
  width:80px;
  margin:20px;
  background-color:blue;
  border:1px solid gray;
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="home-container">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```